# How do you delete a specific line in a text file with python

Tags: python, list

How do you delete a specific line from a python text file that starts with a certain word? For example, if I have the list:

```
cat | apples
bee | orange
dog | bananas
```

How do I delete the whole line that starts with `'bee'`

I tried like del line in a for loop but it didn't work

Comment: It's generally much easier to create a new file, write only the lines you want to keep to that file, and then rename it to the original filename.

Comment: Several ways.  You can read the file into a list, delete the list element, and write the output.  Or, you can copy the file line by line to an output and skip the line you want.  You can't delete a line from a file in place.

Comment: Using `del` won't affect the contents of the original file.

Comment: The easiest thing is to open temporary file. Read lines from the original and write them to the temporary (except the lines you don't want). then rename the temp file to the original.

Comment: It helps to show example code that doesn't work so that our comments make more sense.

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then you can mark the one that best helped you as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confusing the `del` operator with actually modifying a file. Deleting memory read from a file won't delete it from the file. You'll want to store the lines you need into memory, remove the lines you don't need, then write them back to the file. If the lines you need can fit into memory, then this will work:

```
lines = []
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if not line.startswith('bee'):
        lines.append(line)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Read the content of the file into the Python list

```py
with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

2. Filter out lines that start with "bee" `data = [ l for l in data if not l.startswith('bee') ]`
3. Print data back to a file.